# How to loop with two conditions, in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, python-requests

I need to write a code that displays the a return of investments for 0 to 20 years or when the today's value has reached .5 * of the investment initial invested amount. I am stuck with the latter part. When I use an IF statment, I couldn't get any value. Here is my code.

```
def getExpInvestAmt(investAmt, i, n):
    expInvestAmt = int(investAmt * pow(1 + i / 100, n))
    return expInvestAmt

def getPresentValue(exp_invest_amt, d, n):
    adjAmt = int(exp_invest_amt / pow(1 + d / 100, n))
    return adjAmt


def main():
    investAmt = float(input("Enter investment amount:"))
    i = float(input("Enter the expected investment growth rate:"))
    d = float(input("Enter the discount rate:"))
    n = 0
    adjA = 0
    print("Year \t Value at year($) \t Today's worth($)")
    for x in range(0, 21):  
        if adjA < 0.5 * investAmt
            break 
        expected_value = getExpInvestAmt(investAmt, i, n)
        present_value = getPresentValue(expected_value, d, n)
        n += 1
        adjA += 1
        print("{} \t {:,} \t {:,}".format(x, expected_value, present_value))


main()
```

This is what I am suppose to get,

```
Enter investment amount: 10000
Enter the expected investment growth rate: 5
Enter the discount rate: 6.25
Year Value at Year($) Today's worth($)
 1       10,500           9,346
 2       11,025           8,734
 3       11,576           8,163
 4       12,155           7,629
 5       12,763           7,130
 6       13,401           6,663
 7       14,071           6,227
 8       14,775           5,820
 9       15,513           5,439
 10      16,289           5,083
 11      17,103           4,751  # today's value have reached <= 50% of the initial amount program stops.
```

Comment: and what is adjA? Its value is 0 at the begining, so your "if" clause is true, and the loop breaks.

Comment: I don't think your expected result is correct; after 1 year the investment value will be 10500, which discounted at a rate of 6.25% should be 9882, not 9346

Comment: adjA is adjust amount, meaning it's the present value. My thinking was, after present value has been computed, adjA += 1 will give the value of present value to adjA = 0. Therefore when adjA = 0 is = to .5 * initial value, my IF statement would break.

Comment: i'm also aware that the expected result maybe wrong, but it's just for reference to clarify what i meant when the program would not loop till year 20 when the value have reached 50% of the initial investment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code; you don't need `adjA` or `x`. Where you are using `adjA` you should just be using `present_value`, and you can just iterate `n` over the range instead of `x`:

```
def main():
    investAmt = float(input("Enter investment amount:"))
    i = float(input("Enter the expected investment growth rate:"))
    d = float(input("Enter the discount rate:"))
    print("Year \t Value at year($) \t Today's worth($)")
    for n in range(1, 21):  
        expected_value = getExpInvestAmt(investAmt, i, n)
        present_value = getPresentValue(expected_value, d, n)
        print("{} \t {:,} \t {:,}".format(n, expected_value, present_value))
        if present_value < 0.5 * investAmt:
            break
```

To get your expected results for an `investAmt` of 10000 and `i` of 5, you need a `d` value of 12.347528.

Comment: Thank you this worked ! but i hope you can explain what actually happened  or what is the logic behind, when you assign present_value = investAmt. i am new to python and programming in fact, i really appreciate your help.

Comment: @ArifRashed I'm just assigning the value of `investAmt` to `present_value` to ensure the `if` test in the loop has valid data to compare on the first iteration. You could actually remove that assignment and put the `if` statement after the `print`.

Comment: placing it after print worked too! My understanding was python would run the code line by line. I thought it would have iterated it 20 times then realize there was a If statement.

Comment: @ArifRashed as long as the `if` is in the loop (i.e. the same indentation as the other statements) it will get executed on every iteration. Since that is better code to put the `if` there I'll edit the answer to that.